# multithreading : wait for another thread in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have three functions  `funcOne()` , `funcTwo()` & `funcThree()` which are invoked one by one in main thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    funcOne();
    funcTwo();
    funcThree();
}
```

I want the three functions be running in the above order. funcOne() and funcThree() is fine, since they are running on main thread. For `funcTwo()`, it's task is running in anther thread:

```
public static void funcTwo(){
   Thread thread = new Thread(){

        @Override
    public void run(){
           System.out.println("function two is running.");
        }
   }
   thread.start();
}
```

When I run my main function, I see `funcTwo()` runs after `funcThree()` .  How can I make sure `funcTwo()` runs between `funcOne()`? & `funcThree()` ?

Comment: If those three things are meant to be executed in that order, why are you trying to run them in parallel at all?

Comment: I just simulate my practical tasks to this simple scenario. The funcTwo() has to be in a separate thread in my project. Your question is reasonable but it is not the answer I'd consider.

Comment: But your simplification has basically made it meaningless: if you need three things to happen in a specific order, you shouldn't do them in parallel. If the work in `funcTwo()` is maent to finish before you start `funcThree()`, what's the point of doing it on a different thread?

Comment: Do you want funcThree to start after funcTwo starts or after funcTwo finishes?

Comment: I would like to have them run one by one. But funcTwo() has to be in a separate thread.

Comment: Why does it have to be a separate thread?

Comment: Ditto that.  Your example is very contrived.  It's like a script for a play that requires an actor to go off-stage and do a complicated silent dance.  What's the point of the dance if the audience has no way to tell whether the actor did it or not?  Likewise, what's the point of your thread?  If the three tasks are serialized, then it simply does not matter--_can_ not matter--whether the tasks were done by one, two, or three different threads.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    funcOne();
    funcTwo();
    funcThree();
}

public static void funcOne() {
    System.out.println("function one ran");
}

public static void funcTwo(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
         @Override public void run(){
            System.out.println("function two ran.");
         }
    };
    thread.start();
    try { thread.join(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 }    

private static void funcThree() {
    System.out.println("function three ran");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
funcOne();
Thread thread = funcTwo();
thread.Join();
funcThree();
```

This will execute the threads in order, when you call thread.join() it'll wait for the thread to finish, although this will freeze up your GUI or any other processes while it finishes if the thread takes some time.

What do the threads do?

Answer (score 1):

Use Countdownlatch:

```
public class MyTestClass {
    static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        funcOne();
        funcTwo();
        try { latch.await(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        funcThree();
    }

    public static void funcOne() {
        System.out.println("function one ran");
    }

    public static void funcTwo(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override public void run(){
                System.out.println("function two ran.");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private static void funcThree() {
        System.out.println("function three ran");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, but, I think, is answer to your question.

```
public static Thread funcTwo(){
   Thread thread = new Thread(){

        @Override
    public void run(){
           System.out.println("function two is running.");
        }
   }
   thread.start();
   return thread;
}

funcOne();
Thread thread = funcTwo();
thread.Join();
funcThree();
```

Comment: Why do you return thread? Can I just thread.join() inside funcTwo()?

Answer (score 0):

return created thread object from funcTwo and use thread.join() after funcThree

Or use CountDownLatch if you have more then one threads.